# Interface Builder Content Border Text

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra

I've been able to add a content border to the bottom of my interface for a macOS application. How in the world do I add text to it like the bottom bar of the Finder application? Any ideas?

Comment: Post your UI screen shots and piece of code where you feeling trouble.

Comment: There is NO code, there are no screenshots.... This question doesn't require any of that. For an example just open Finder and look at the status bar at the bottom.

Comment: Add an NSTextField to show text.

Comment: If i drag a text field it just doesn't show up.